# AirshipConfigOptions: null is not a valid development app key

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, urbanairship.com

In push notification using Urbanship in aandroid. I am getting error in Airship configuration file. The file is reside inside WWW folder along with assets.

[image]

I think the configuration file is at right place and this is my config.properties.

```
developmentAppKey = _RfPLPfVfToWrU23hfRs5NivA
developmentAppSecret = uTqytKedER211CKXfhCpt4-G-w
productionAppKey = Your Production App Key
productionAppSecret = Your Production Secret

#transport is "gcm" or "helium".
transport = gcm

gcmSender = 655763901391
inProduction = false

iapEnabled = false

# 2 = Log.VERBOSE; 3 = Log.DEBUG; 4 = Log.INFO;
# 5 = Log.WARN; 6 = Log.ERROR; 7 = Log.ASSERT;
developmentLogLevel = 3
productionLogLevel = 6
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove ".sample" extension of that text file i.e your file name should be "airshipconfig.properties" not "airshipconfig.properties.sample" because in downloaded zip folder ".sample" extension is there hope this will help you

Comment: Let me try this. Thanks for your response